# Best fit affine transformation is the same as average?

Tags: statistics, affine-geometry

Suppose I have two lattices of points $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and I calculate the best affine transformation $A\to B$ in the least squares sense (an account of this may be found in hrcak.srce.hr/file/1425). In particular, the translational part of the transformation is a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Could I retrieve the same vector by taking the vector that takes the average of $A$ into that of $B$, i.e. $(\sum_{i=1}^n(b_i - a_i))/n$?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you prove that the optimal transformation has a diagonal matrix?

Comment: I think as stated the answer is no, you cannot retrieve the best affine transformation in least squares sense *just* by mapping  the average of $A$ to the average of $B$.  However that is a consequence, and using that insight reduces the problem (of finding an affine transformation) to finding a best linear transformation  (which is what you perhaps want to know).

Comment: Hey Ron, I can't and it shouldn't. For example it may be that $B$ is a rotation of $A$ in which the linear part wouldn't be diagonal.

Comment: Hardmath, thanks! I would like to know though how you could prove that it is a consequence.